# "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given."

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve records using AJAX json and I'm trying to send the result data through a JSON format back to the client. (Below is what I tried)

```
$vote = users_details::where('vote', '=', 1)->get();
return response()->json(['success' => true, 'vote' => $vote ]);
```

but unfortunately and sadly not working instead, it throws me this error.

> "The Response content must be a string or object implementing
>   __toString(), "boolean" given."

I tried to

```
dd(var_dump($vote));
```

and it shows me the retrieved data so i guess the issue was in the return JSON part and I even tried

```
$vote = users_details::where('vote', '=', 1)->get()->toJson();
return response()->json(['success' => true, 'vote' => $vote ]);
```

and it throws me this error (refer below)

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\toJson()

any ideas, help, suggestion, recommendation, clues please?

UPDATE: the retrieved data using

```
dd(var_dump(users_details::where('vote', '=', 1)->get(['firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname', 'branch', 'position', 'img'])));
```

the result

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[205]
protected 'items' => 
array (size=12)
  0 => 
    object(App\users_details)[206]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  1 => 
    object(App\users_details)[207]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  2 => 
    object(App\users_details)[208]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  3 => 
    object(App\users_details)[209]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  4 => 
    object(App\users_details)[210]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  5 => 
    object(App\users_details)[211]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  6 => 
    object(App\users_details)[212]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  7 => 
    object(App\users_details)[213]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  8 => 
    object(App\users_details)[214]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  9 => 
    object(App\users_details)[215]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  10 => 
    object(App\users_details)[216]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  11 => 
    object(App\users_details)[217]
      protected 'table' => string 'employee' (length=8)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=6)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
```

null

Comment: What your `$vote = users_details::where('vote', '=', 1)->get();` returns, probably some character that made it `text/html`, any tag or what?

Comment: theres no lag, actually theres a blob column (attachment).

Comment: I guess it was the blob column because I tried to get only the specified columns and it works.

Comment: A blob is binary data and that is valid unless you made an accessor to get an `img` ready tag.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Assume I want to send the image over the json response, any suggestion, recommendation for me to do?

Comment: Build the image from client site, just send raw (unformatted) json data.

Comment: any ideas how to apply it base from the existing code above?

Comment: Show you `$vote` data/code. Result of `$vote = users_details::where('vote', '=', 1)->get(); dd($vote)`.

Comment: @TheAlpha: Please see my updated post.

Comment: Please use `dd($vote->toArray())`.

Comment: it gives me no result, e.g. white screen, no render data appear.

Comment: @CodeDemon I faced similar issue, then I checked the database and it had fields containing French characters (like à) which caused the problem.